# Changed order for parse_expr()

Tags: sympy

I use parse_expr("-5 + 2*x + 3 - 7*x + 5 - 3*x", evaluate=False).
According to documentation for evaluate=False, I expected to keep the order of the expression:

"When False, the order of the arguments will remain as they were in the string ..."

But the result is sorted:
-7*x - 3*x + 2*x - 5 + 3 + 5

sympy=1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as advertised:

```
>>> u = parse_expr("-5 + 2*x + 3 - 7*x + 5 - 3*x", evaluate=False); u.args
(-5, 2*x, 3, -7*x, 5, -3*x)
```

The printer, however, prints them in sorted order. It seems like there should be an easier way to do the following, but it works:

```
>>> s=StrPrinter(dict(order='none'))
>>> s._print_Add(u)
-5 + 2*x + 3 - 7*x + 5 - 3*x
```

Comment: Thank you @smichr
That explains it and helps me in any case.

Comment: @smichr u = parse_expr('(foo < 0) & (foo > bar)', evaluate=False)
u.args
(foo > bar, foo < 0) ...any way to print the original order here?

Comment: Hmm. I can't do this even with `And(*args, evaluate=False)` (and it doesn't appear to be a printing issue b/c inspection of the args shows that they reorder).