# Enumerate coefficients

Tags: python, sympy

I want to make a program to detect a correct expanding.
For example:
I want to expand `(x + 2)*(x - 3)`.
The solution is `x*x -x -6`
But `x*x +2*x -3*x -6` is a correct solution.
I want to detect such correct (but unsimplified) expansions.

Comment: What have you tried, and what specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: What you're describing isn't really about coefficients, it's about traversing the expression tree. If you `print(expr)`, has sympy already simplified it for you?

Comment: I am sorry, it was not clear. I wanted to collect each terms of each coefficient. I have found a solution:
(sympify("x**2-3*x+2*x-6", evaluate=False)).args give me exactly what i wanted:
(x² ,-3x, 2X, -6) and not (x² ,-x, -6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow a user to input the expression as a string and parse the expression with `evaluate=False` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58667300/changed-order-for-parse-expr) you can compare the number of arguments in what is entered with the fully simplified version.

```
>>> expr = (x - 3)*(x + 2)
>>> expanded = expand(expr)
>>> ans = 'x*x +2*x -3*x -6'  # obtained from user
>>> if S(ans) == expanded:  # it's right
...     if len(parse_expr(ans, evaluate=False).args) != len(expanded.args):
...         print('right, but not simplified')
```

The unsimplified `ans` will have 4 arguments while the expanded form will have 3.